# Ruby on Rails: Allow user to submit to two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

I have an app that allows a user to create a new project. In the create new project form, for each field, they have the option of creating new data to go in that field, or select data from previous projects, for example, type in a new client name, or select an excisting client from the project database, that has been entered before.

Now I have set up a relations table between technologies and projects, to allow the user to select multiple technologies to go with one project.

My problem is when I try to allow them to also submit more technologies if they arn't present in the collection_select.

Here is my new view:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "form" %>


<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

<div class="client">
<%= label_tag :new_client, "Client" %><br/>
<%= text_field_tag :new_client, nil, :maxlength => 30 %>
Or
<%= f.select( :client, Project.all.map {|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "Select a previous Client") %>
</div>



<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>       
 <%=  text_field_tag :tech, nil, :maxlength => %>        
 <%= ab.label "All Tech"%> </br>
 <%= collection_select( :technols, :id, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true } ) %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

<div class="create_button">
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save New Project", :class => "button",  :confirm => "Are you sure you want to save the new project?" %>
  </div>
</div>    
</div> 

<% end %>  

<div class="back_button2">
<%= button_to "Back", projects_path , :class => "button", :method => "get" %>
</div>
```

And here is my create and new action:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
        @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

        @all_technols = Technol.all
        tech_ids = params[:technols][:id].reject(&:blank?) unless params[:technols].nil?
        @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end

end

def create

    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @technol.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?


    params[:technols][:id].each do |tech|

        if !tech.empty?
        @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => tech) 
        end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I would appreciate any help at all, I am really stuck with this problem. I am new to rails, so please remember this when trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question you want to have:

```
find_or_create_by_name
```

in your technologies model, which will create a new record if none could be found in your DB.
Check out this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association) which is great for beginners :)

and also the [reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there, my problem is that I am wanting to use the collection select so the users can select many technologies, and allow them to enter new ones as well. From what I understand, I wouldn't be able to do that with `find_or_create_by_name `?

Comment: No therefore you would need an additional field
But that would confuse your users. What you can do is a collection select and a link "add new technology" which will open a form via JS on the current page

Comment: Ok, is there anyway that you would be able to show me how to go about that? I've never used JS before

Comment: Yay, when I wanted to achieve something similar i watched a screencast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll give that a watch and let you know how I get on